# Play 2.5 framework and SQL Server 2008 R2 connection

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, playframework-2.0

I'm very noob at Java and Play 2.5 framework but I'd like to connect to a SQL Server 2008 R2 database via VPN.

I downloaded the file jtds-1.3.1-dist.zip, I extracted it and copied into the *libexec* folder.

I inserted this line in *build.sbt* file:

```
val appDependencies = Seq(
"net.sourceforge.jtds" % "jtds" % "1.3.1"
)
```

This is the application.conf file:

```
## Database Connection Pool
# https://www.playframework.com/documentation/latest/SettingsJDBC
# ~~~~~
# Play doesn't require a JDBC database to run, but you can easily enable one.
#
# libraryDependencies += jdbc
#
play.db {
# The combination of these two settings results in "db.default" as the
# default JDBC pool:
config = "db"
default = "default"

# Play uses HikariCP as the default connection pool.  You can override
# settings by changing the prototype:
prototype {
# Sets a fixed JDBC connection pool size of 50
hikaricp.minimumIdle = 50
hikaricp.maximumPoolSize = 50
}
}

## JDBC Datasource
# https://www.playframework.com/documentation/latest/JavaDatabase
# https://www.playframework.com/documentation/latest/ScalaDatabase
# ~~~~~
# Once JDBC datasource is set up, you can work with several different
# database options:
#
# Slick (Scala preferred option): https://www.playframework.com          /documentation/latest/PlaySlick
# JPA (Java preferred option): https://playframework.com/documentation/latest/JavaJPA
# EBean: https://playframework.com/documentation/latest/JavaEbean
# Anorm: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/latest/ScalaAnorm
#
db {
# You can declare as many datasources as you want.
# By convention, the default datasource is named `default`

# https://www.playframework.com/documentation/latest/Developing-with-the-H2-Database
#default.driver = org.h2.Driver
#default.url = "jdbc:h2:mem:play"
#default.username = sa
#default.password = ""
default.url = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://xyz.aaa.bbb.global:1433/MyDB;instance=MSSQLSERVER"
default.driver = net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
default.username = username
default.password = "password"


# You can turn on SQL logging for any datasource
# https://www.playframework.com/documentation/latest/Highlights25#Logging-SQL-statements
default.logSql=true
}
```

Unfortunately, I always get this error:

> Cannot connect to database [default]

Could someone help me, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I used sqljdbc42.jar to the connection.
I didn't add any line to the build.sbt file just the jar into the lib folder and these two lines to the application.conf file:

> default.driver=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
>     default.url="jdbc:sqlserver://xxx.yyy.zzz.global:1433;databaseName=MyDB;user=uname;password=pword;"